# Is there a .NET ArcGIS Server REST Wrapper library that supports 10.6 or later?

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis-rest-api

I am looking for a .NET wrapper for the ArcGIS Server REST API.  I have found several on nuget and github but they haven't been updated in several years.

I didn't see a a REST wrapper on https://github.com/Esri?q=&type=&language=c%23 but maybe they rolled that in to something else?

What are all the cool kids using in 2021?

***The ArcGIS Server version I am consuming is 10.6***

Comment: ArcGIS Runtime I suppose? https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/

Comment: @Berend it's been a few years, but I though the ArcGIS runtime was license restricted to prevent it from being used as a service (I didn't mention that in my question).